# What am I doing wrong when a Linux app doesn't find an .so file?

Tags: linux, libraries, path

I have just downloaded, *configure*'d, *make*'d and *make install*'ed the [Google Log Library](http://google-glog.googlecode.com/) to my computer. It built all required files (as far as I can see) and copied the .so file (libglog.so.0.0.0) to /usr/local/lib. Then it created two symbolic links called "libglog.so.0" and "libglog.so" that point to that shared object file:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1     16 /usr/local/lib/libglog.so -> libglog.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1     16 /usr/local/lib/libglog.so.0 -> libglog.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 498381 /usr/local/lib/libglog.so.0.0.0
```

Now I'm trying to execute a program that uses the library, but when I start it, I get the error message that it can't open the so-file:

```
cloud:/home/blam/redirector/redirector2# ./redirector
./redirector: error while loading shared libraries: libglog.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

*/usr/local/lib* is included in my */etc/ld.so.conf* file, and another library that's located in this directory is loaded correctly.

What am I doing wrong here? What am I missing?

Comment: Just found out that setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/local/lib fixes the problem - but still: why is it not working without that tweak?

Comment: What does ldd /home/blam/redirector/redirector2/redirector return?

Comment: Now it returns the correct library, but good to know that that command (ldd) exists!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, fixed it myself. I had to call **ldconfig** manually.

Looks as if some tool modified the *ld.so.conf*, but did not update the database.

Comment: Actually, you need to re-run `ldconfi` every time some library changes, not just when chanching `ld.so.conf`. So it's normal you had to run it.

Comment: Okay, good to know.